# Solidity Order of Operations - Logical NOT

Tags: operator-precedence, solidity

I have a question concerning the order of operations in Solidity. In the docs it says that the logical NOT operation takes precedence over the logical AND operation. The thing is, when I have an `if` statement like that `if(false && !function())` I thought the function is called first because of the order of operations, but in reality the short-circuiting of the `&&` operator is done first. So my question is: Why?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the two operators `||` and `&&` apply the common short-circuiting rules, as described in [Solidity document](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#value-types):

> The operators `||` and `&&` apply the common short-circuiting rules. This means that in the expression `f(x) || g(y)`, if `f(x)` evaluates to `true`, `g(y)` will not be evaluated even if it may have side-effects.

Because of the common short-circuiting rules, the behavior described here is exactly the same as many other languages, e.g Java or Scala. Here is a Scala REPL demonstration:

```scala
scala> def foo(x: Int): Boolean = { if (x >= 0) true else ??? }
foo: (x: Int)Boolean

scala> foo(10)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> foo(-10)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:230)
  at .foo(<console>:11)
  ... 32 elided

scala> if (false && !foo(-10)) "boo" else "bar"
res2: String = bar
```